# G++ shows error about undefined namespace

Tags: c++, gcc, header, include, compiler-errors

I have 3 files to compile with G++, the main file is like this:

```
//main.cpp

#include "test.hpp"

int main(int argc,char** args) {
  //
}
```

The second file is the header file:

```
//test.hpp

namespace shared {
  class test {

    //constructor 
    test();
  };
}
```

The last file is the code file for test.hpp

```
//test.cpp

shared::test::test() {
  //
}
```

And I compile using G++ this way:

```
g++ -c main.cpp test.cpp
```

However, G++ complains about undefined identifier 'shared' in the file 'test.cpp'. In the command line I already pass in file 'main.cpp', which includes the header file. How to fix this? I only want to have all the '#include's be in main.cpp, and no where else.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know about namespace shared when it deals with test.cpp?

Comment: isn't the 'main.cpp' there in the command line before test.cpp. and the header file already included in main.cpp

Comment: They're still different files, processed one after the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `#include "test.hpp"` at the beggining of `test.cpp`.

Compiler doesn't care about the order of files in the commandline. It only affects the linker.
Please also note, that the usual way of compiling multi-file projects is to compile each of them to different sub-object like so:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o
g++ test.cpp -o test.o
ld main.o test.o -o program[.exe]
```

This allows you to recompile only the files that really did change. If you think about it for a while, you'll find out that a `.cpp` file can contain many headers without a problem; however, the compilation time will increase when your headers will start to have many headers included. Forward declarations can help solve those issues, yet with your simple example simple solution will work.

Comment: but i want to keep all '#include's in the main.cpp file only. coz i have multiple namespace levels in subdirectories. i shouldn't do some include like "#include '../../../topnamespace/subnamespace/someheader.hpp"

Comment: @PaulDinh: That's not how C++ works, no matter how badly you may want it. You could always concatenate *all* your source files (in the right order) and compile that, if you really wanted...

Comment: Your comment isn't entirely clear to me, but usually you should think about this files as pairs of `.h`/`.cpp`; with the first containing interface, and the second implementation.

Comment: @KerrekSB which will significantly increase compilation time (each build is a full rebuild). Hence my addition to my answer.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I know that the idea is insane, but it wasn't mine :-)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: yeah, the files hpp&cpp of the same class are in the same dir, so it's ok. but if class 'abc' needs to declare a property of class 'xyz' which is in another multi-leveled namespace, the #include looks terrible. coz my namespaces are at multi-levels

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily have to split up all the files so the directory matches the namespace. If namespaces (or logical units) have to contact each other, it might be a problem with your design. Anyway, you could also add `-I` option for every namespace dir you have, to keep `#include`s short.

Comment: i'm thinking of using 1 single file 'main.hpp' which would contain all the includes, and then each cpp file would include this main.hpp

Comment: We already told you why this is a bad idea, but of course you can learn it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to say `#include "test.hpp"` in your `test.cpp` file. The namespace declaration has to be known.